# Else vs new IF - Readability and Performance

Tags: c#, performance, if-statement, code-readability

I'm working in C# using Visual Studio and have been going over my code trying to improve its readability. I came across this [site](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/top-15-best-practices-for-writing-super-readable-code--net-8118), that lists 15 best practices. #7 - Avoid Deep Nesting, it talks about If statements and says instead of using Else, make another If statement.

This got me wondering about the difference in the instructions between the two. Would using additional If statements cost more performance than just using Else?

Any advice would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The number of conditions evaluated in either case is the same, the only difference is the nesting. There will most likely be no noticeable difference in performance between the two, and there are different opinions about which one is "better" from a readability and best-practice point of view.

- In the first example, each condition is evaluated until one returns `false`, unless they're all `true`, in which case the middle (most nested) `if` block will run.
- In the second example, the *inverse* of each condition is evaluated until one returns `true`, unless they're all `false`, in which case the last `if` block will run.

Another way to write your test method to avoid nesting (depending on the actual language) is to combine the conditions with the ['&&' operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-and-operator)
, which will evaluate them in order until one of them returns false (and if they're all true, then the code in the `if` block will run):

```
// Combine the conditions with '&&', which will evaluate
// evaluate them in order until one of them returns false
if (is_writable($folder) &&
    $fp = fopen($file_path, 'w') &&
    $stuff = get_some_stuff() &&
    fwrite($fp,$stuff))
{
    // ...
}
else
{
    return false;
}
```